# Creating multiple tables using SugarORM gives IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

I have two classes, *Inventory* and *Recipe*. The problem I have is that I cannot add items to the Recipe table. I get the following error message:

> *java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table RECIPE has no column named NAME (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO RECIPE(ID,INGREDIENTS,HOW_TO,NAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?)*

This happens when I launch the method `goToSearchResults(View view)`, located in `MainActivity`.

Inventory looks as follows:

```
    import com.orm.SugarRecord;


    public class Inventory extends SugarRecord {
        String foodType;
        String foodName;
        String foodQuantity;
        public Inventory(){

     }

public Inventory(String foodType, String foodName, String foodQuantity) {
    this.foodType = foodType;
    this.foodName = foodName;
    this.foodQuantity = foodQuantity;
}

public String getFoodType() {
    return foodType;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return  foodType +
            " " + foodName + '\'' +
            " " +foodQuantity + '\''
            ;
}

public void setFoodType(String foodType) {
    this.foodType = foodType;
}

public String getFoodQuantity() {
    return foodQuantity;
}

public void setFoodQuantity(String foodQuantity) {
    this.foodQuantity = foodQuantity;
}

public String getFoodName() {
    return foodName;
}

public void setFoodName(String foodName) {
    this. foodName = foodName;
}
}
```

The class Recipe looks as follows.

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class Recipe extends SugarRecord {

String name;
String ingredients;
String howTo;
public Recipe() {
}

public Recipe(String name, String ingredients, String howTo) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.howTo = howTo;

}

public String getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}

public void setIngredients(String ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

public String getHowTo() {
    return howTo;
}

public void setHowTo(String howTo) {
    this.howTo = howTo;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}



public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Recipe{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", ingredients='" + ingredients + '\'' +
            ", howTo='" + howTo + '\'' +
            '}';
}


}
```

When I try to add items to the Inventory table, I use the following two lines:

```
 inventory = new Inventory(foodType, foodName.getText().toString(), foodQuantity.getText().toString());
 inventory.save();
```

This works fine. Items are added to Inventory in the way that I want them to.

However, when I try to put items into the Recipe table, using the following two lines (initialized in the main activity). In the main activity, I have a method, which is a dummy method used for debugging purposes.

```
public void goToSearchResults(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchResults.class);
    recipe = new Recipe("Filet Mignon", "Beef, Potatoes", "Use the owen to cook the potatoes real good -_^");
    recipe.save();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Why doesn’t this work? To me, it seems like the two classes and their usage are identical to each other, and only one works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try my suggestion hope it works :

1. Update your Sugar to the latest version which is [1.5 here](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/releases)
2. Try to modify your manifest configure : like modify the name of the database, and correct the location of your class entities. [here](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)

I solve my issue following the steps above.